# Hiding columns and its contents in a table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have created a table and now i need to hide specific columns in the table by css applied to the column(not by inline).

HTML:

```
<table id='table1'>
  <colgroup>
    <col>
    <col>
  </colgroup>
  <tr>
    <th>ISBN</th>
    <th>Title</th>
    <th>Price</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3476896</td>
    <td>My first HTML</td>
    <td>$53</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>5869207</td>
   <td>My first CSS</td>
   <td>$49</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I have tried giving background-color and color to `colgroup` by       `$($('#table1').find('col:eq(1)')).css('color',red')`

This code works. But when i tried the same code for `display : none` or `overflow:hidden`,it doesn't works. The `display:none` property hiding the column but not the contents of the `td`s in it. Could anyone please suggest a best way to hide the column, its contents by css.

I need to hide the columns dynamically using css and also in the case the table has more than 100 rows and 25 columns.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you creating table dynamically

Comment: i am creating rows dynamically. hiding a column by finding each `td` is a time-consuming process. so i am approaching `colgroup`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have come up with solution for this by adding classes to the `td` and getting it.

HTML:

```
<table id='table1'>
  <colgroup>
    <col>
    <col>
  </colgroup>
  <tr>
    <th class='col1'>ISBN</th>
    <th class='col2'>Title</th>
    <th class='col3'>Price</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class='col1'>3476896</td>
    <td class='col2'>My first HTML</td>
    <td class='col3'>$53</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td class='col1'>5869207</td>
   <td class='col2'>My first CSS</td>
   <td class='col3'>$49</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Way:

```
$('.col1').css('visibility','hidden');
```

Please post if you have alternates. Hope it will be useful.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $('td:nth-child(2),th:nth-child(2)').hide();
});
```

This hides the 2nd column.